# Adding a class to menu <li> and then clicking the link using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am trying to use jquery to add a class to my css menu it adds the class selected when you click on the menu item but it doesnt actually click the hyperlink.

edit: it adds an `li` class. but when I click, it doesn't do anything

**Html:**

```
<div id="nav"> 
 <nav>
   <ul class="topmenu">
    <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.aspx">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.topmenu a:link').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.closest('ul').children('li').removeClass('selected');
            $this.parent().addClass('selected');
        });
    });

</script>
```

I need it to click the link once its assigned the class "selected", strange because the manual click doesnt seem to work?

**css:**

```
#nav 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
nav a.current
{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 950px;
}
nav ul
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 8px 0 0;
}
nav li
{
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    left: -45px;
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:active
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 11px 17px 0;

}
nav li:hover, .home-link a, .current_page_item a:link, .current_page_item a:visited, a.children_openend, .topmenu li.selected a
{
    background: url("images/dc/menu-selected.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}



nav a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a click manually by using

```
.trigger("click");
```

So after you do

```
addClass("selected");
```

Just tag a trigger() call on the end:

```
addClass("selected").trigger("click");
```

Edit:

Instead of doing that, you could just manually redirect the browser:

```
addClass("selected");
window.location.href = $this.attr("href");
```

The .trigger() wouldn't work as you are triggering it on the li, not the a. My apologies.

Edit again:

If I understand you right, you want the li to still have the class once the link has been clicked and the new page loaded. You could do this with CSS. If you give each list item a class relating to the page, eg:

```
<li class="home-link">....</li>
```

And on each page, add an id to the body tag:

```
<body id="home-page">
```

Then you can do your styling to th currently selected li using:

```
#home-page .home-link {}
```

Does that help?

Comment: ...disregard my previous comment about recursion. The click is on the parent. As such, the `.trigger('click')` won't affect the `<a>` at all.

Comment: @Jack: That works, but obviously when the new pages loads it scrubs the class "selected" and then my menu item is no longer highlighten to the user. Have a look at this site, they use a css method, but i dont know how they apply the <a id> current? http://www.austinclassicalballet.com/director.htm

Comment: i will try it 2moro and get back to you.. when i first tried it, i couldnt get it to work... sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `e.preventDefault();`, which disabled the default behavior of the `<a>`.

Also, be aware that jQuery doesn't currently support the `:link` selector. As such, your selector will only work in certain browsers.

You may want to use this instead:

```
$('.topmenu a[href]').click(function (e) {
```

---

**EDIT:**

Of course following the link will cause a new page to load, and any changes to the DOM previously made will be lost.

If you're just trying to style the link for the current page, give this a try:

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

$('a[href$="' + page + '"]').parent().addClass('selected');
```

When the page loads, it will get the last item in the `pathname` of `window.location`, and concatenate that into a selector to select the `<a>` element for that page.

Comment: I didn't do the down-voting, but I think it's because if you remove the preventDefault(), the browser will just take you to the new location and not execute the required code first.

Comment: @Jack: The code will execute before the link is followed. I've interpreted *"but it doesnt actually click the hyperlink"* to mean the hyperlink is not followed. OP isn't exactly clear on that point.

Comment: @patrick dw - i checked with firebug, it seems to add the class, then remove it? (therefore my selected background image via css wont fire) but the links work.. any ideas?

Comment: @PD24: If you want the link to be followed, then a new page will be loaded, and any changes to the DOM that you made on the previous page will be lost. Are you trying to give some style to the link that represents the current page?

Comment: @patrick dw: i am trying to keep the menu item selected with a different colour so the user knows what page they are on. I decided to use jquery to add the class "selected" on click therefore firing my css..

Comment: @PD24: Yes, the class is being added, but then the new page is loaded. The new page doesn't know about the change you made on the old page. I  just updated my answer with a solution. Give it a shot.

Comment: @patrick dw: it works but how do i keep my styles enabled in the new page?

Comment: @PD24: Which styles? You mean more than just the link? You need to include your CSS in each page that uses it. Any styling that comes from JavaScript needs to be applied to each individual page.

Comment: ...the new code I posted should run when the page loads. *Not* inside a click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm. If you want the link to 'be clicked', you have to remove the following line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

But, the link will go to the page set in its `href`, I don't know if that's you want.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing what you tell it to do: `e.preventDefault();` inside an event handler prevent the default behavior for that event.