# Add class to <li> when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

That's the html of my menu:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#a" class="active">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b" >B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c" >C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d" >D</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want that, after I clicked on a link in the menu, the active class will be added to the clicked `<li>`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use jQuery for this?

Comment: Good luck. What have you tried?

Comment: duplicated entry of that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565321/adding-a-class-to-menu-li-and-then-clicking-the-link-using-jquery

or that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688778/jquery-add-class-to-current-li-and-remove-prev-li-when-click-inside-li-a

or that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435265/jquery-adding-class-to-the-li-element-after-the-link-is-clicked-and-deselectin

Comment: It's not a duplicate since he is not asking for a jquery solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery

```
    $("li a").click(function() {
    $('li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

**[DEMO Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/emJ4w/1/)**

Comment: it doesn't remove the active class of the older one

Answer (score 2):

He is not asking for a jQuery solution. But that jQuery would be the ideal choice, here is how to do it with javascript, best practices, event delegation and modern. Perhaps someone learns something new from it as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/N9Hem/

```
window.onload = function(){

    (function(){
        var els = [];
        var doc = document;
        var get = function(id){return doc.getElementById(id);};

        get('clickable').onclick = function(evt){
            evt = evt || window.event;
            var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
            els = doc.querySelectorAll('#clickable a');

            if(el.nodeName == "A"){
                for(var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1){
                    els[i].className = '';
                };
                el.className = 'active';
            };

        };

    })();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery then you could use code like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".nav a").click(function () {
        $(".nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){
    $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a prototype that doesn't use jquery as you didn't request it on your question.
It searches for the current element with the active class, remove it and add the class to the clicked one.

Javasript Function

```
function activeThis(element){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
    current.className = null;
    element.className="active";
}
```

HTML code

```
<a href="#b" onclick="activeThis(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got what you want... I add eventHandlers to `<ul>`. On click remove clicked from previous elem and set clicked-class (if current class is active??)

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#a" class="active">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
    var clickedElem = null;
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (clickedElem)
            clickedElem.removeAttribute("class");

        // check if e.srcElement.className is active?? that's what you want?
        e.srcElement.className = "clicked";
        clickedElem = e.srcElement;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its better to add one event handler on the UL instead.

Comment: ...and make sure its cross browser!

Answer (score 0):

This one should works for you

```
elems =document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    elems[i].className="";
                };
                this.className = "active";
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work

```
var navlinks = document.getElementByClass('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < navlinks.length; i++) {
    if(navlinks[i].className == 'active'){
        navlinks[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'YOUR CLASS';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

thats quite easy

**jQuery CODE:**

```
$('.nav li a').on('click',function(){ 
 $('.nav li').each(function() {
    var anc=$(this).find('a');
    if(anc.hasClass('active'))
    { 
       $(anc).removeClass('active');
    }
 })
  $(this).addClass('active');
 })
```

**Edited:**
Code is refined

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Why is the DV for this ?

Comment: I agree that there was spelling mistake in my code,as i had manually wrote it not a running copy.i cant beleive i got a down vote for that :(

Comment: my example works. but downvote for that, that the example is not working at him.... well i have flagged this question.. because there are many many many examples of this topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Check my fiddle

I hope this is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/ftZzs/

```
a:visited 
{
    color:green;
}
a:active  {color:yellow;}

a:link {color:red;}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that is because the link color resets to green after you release the mouse button. As far as I understand the question the link should remain yellow until the next link is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.nav li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to attach the `click` event to the `a`:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YSYpw/)